# Trying to use memoization object to check if an argument has already been computed... can't seem to handle using objects as arguments

Tags: javascript, object, callback, closures, memoization

So I am using an inner function for closure and to be able to pass in an unknown amount of arguments. The function is supposed to use memoization of some kind (I chose to use an object) to check and see if the result of running arguments through a callback have already been computed and stored. Here is the function I have written so far...

```
function memoize(func) {
    // Define an object to hold results
    let obj = {}
    // define an inner function for closure that takes an argument
    function inner(...arg) {
        if (obj[arg]) {
            return obj[arg]
        } else {
            obj[arg] = func(...arg);
            return obj[arg];
        }
    }
    return inner;
}
```

I am getting an error that my function "should work with objects as arguments"... Currently, I am unsure why my current code WON'T work with objects as arguments... So if someone could explain that, it would be greatly appreciated. Here is the algorithm used to test my function...

```
it('should work with objects as arguments', () => {
    const firstTime = timeCheck({ foo: 'bar' });
    wait(5);
    const secondTime = fastTimeCheck({ foo: 'bar' });
    wait(5);
    expect(firstTime).to.not.equal(secondTime);
    expect(fastTimeCheck({ foo: 'bar' })).to.equal(secondTime);
    expect(fastTimeCheck({ foo: 'bar' })).to.not.equal(fastTimeCheck({ different: 'result' }));
  });
```

If you have the time. I would appreciate knowing why my current function is not working with objects as arguments... Also, how can I modify what I have written to satisfy the test algorithm.

Comment: Object keys must be strings, not objects.

Comment: Ok, so what exactly does that mean in my case?

Comment: It means you shouldn't use this for functions with object arguments. Or maybe you could change the key to `JSON.stringify(arg)`

Comment: Thanks! That worked! Now I just have to read up on it and figure out why lol!

Answer (score 1):

> Property names are string or Symbol. Any other value, including a number, is coerced to a string. This outputs 'value', since 1 is coerced into '1'. See [Property accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#property_names)

So when you call `obj[arg]`, you actually call something like `obj[arg.toString()]`. Here `arg` is the array of the arguments, like `[{foo: 'bar'}]`. Try calling `[{foo: 'bar'}].toString()` and you'll get `[object Object]`. See [Array.prototype.toString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString) and [Object.prototype.toString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString).

That means for every object argument, you will get the same key.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain why it wasn't working with objects as arguments!

Comment: If you print your cache object when debugging the code, you could have already found that.